# How to avoid overflowing PNG frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have to objects. One of them is `PNG` formatted image frame and the other is just an `JPG` formatted image.

When I drag the JPG formatted image to `PNG` formatted frame, `(jQuery's drag and drop function)` my `JPG` formatted image overflows through **PNG formatted frame**. I dont want `JPG` image to **overflow through my PNG frame**. How can I overcome it?

I'm uploading an image that you'll understand my problem easily..

[image]

Comment: Does the PNG have transparency inside the frame, and white background colour outside of it?

Comment: So... you want to get the second result? I think it's not possible to do it with Javascript in an easy way. Maybe your PNG has transparency outside the frame and that's the problem (in other words, JPG background is not "overflowing" the PNG image, it's just that the PNG image doesn't have a solid color outside the frame).

Comment: Both PNG's inside and outside of have transpapency.

Comment: You should provide a jsfiddle in order to get some help i think

Comment: just edit your frame png to have transparency inside and white colour outside it :)

Comment: If you're getting the random bleeding you've shown in the screenshot, then I'd say your frame image is at fault; you've probably just not painted it very well -- it looks like you've gone over it with a white spraycan tool but just not covered every spot. Use a flood-fill tool instead and you won't get that kind of issue.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming HTML5 Canvas is allowed:-

- Create a new canvas in script and get the 2d context.
- drawImage to the context your JPG image.
- Create a second canvas for your frame and get its 2d context.
- drawImage your PNG to this second canvas.
- Call getImageData on both contexts to get two arrays of bytes in RGBA order.
- Process each pixel by checking the alpha on the second canvas and combining RGB as required.
- Call putImageData to save the result back to the context.
- You can then drawImage the canvas you wrote to in other script, or use canvas.toDataURL("image/png") to get a src url.

Answer (score 0):

There are well-supported canvas and SVG solutions, as well as bleeding edge support for [CSS Masks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/).